# AG Grid SSRM Tree Data with Infinite Scrolling

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a use-case where I need to render millions of rows using `treeData` and `rowModelType: "serverSide"` with AG Grid React. Does AG Grid support infinite scrolling of server-side `treeData`? I need to be able to infinite scroll at all levels of the tree data (the root level and sub-tree levels when you expand a tree data row).

Basically looking to only get a subset of child rows (via leveraging of the `startRow`/`endRow` fields of from the server-side `getRows` request) when a tree data group row is expanded and then have the grid request more rows when we scroll down far enough in the expanded child group set -- but I am not observing that behavior from the grid.

The reason for this is because an expanded tree group in my case could have millions of entries and I only want to process whatever is visible on screen and not the entire set for obvious performance reasons.

Comment: You would need to modify the server-side logic here to fetch a subset of child rows for each expanded group row. This would involve modifying the ```getRows``` in the server-side datasource to accept a ```startRow``` and ```endRow```, and then use these parameters to fetch a subset of child rows from the server.

Comment: So I have that information (i.e. `startRow`/`endRow`) already available from the `getRows` request object. The issue is, it appears that AG Grid SSRM Tree Data does not seem to "care" about it. By that I mean, I have my server side return data based on that start/end window info, but I do not see the `getRows` callback invoked again when I reach the "next window" section in my expanded tree data group. Hope that explanation made sense.

Comment: The [SSRM with tree data](https://angular-grid.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/server-side-model-tree-data/) is a more complex scenario as it involves dealing with hierarchical data. The Server-Side Datasource in AG Grid allows you to specify which rows are expandable and group keys. So, possible, you should use [getChildrenCount](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/server-side-model-api-reference/#reference-serverSideRowModel-getChildCount) to determine the number of children of a row on the server.

Comment: Hmm, I don't believe `getChildrenCount` is applicable to my use-case. The issue isn't about determining the number of child rows a parent row has on the server. It is about rendering child rows in a paginated fashion with `startRow`/`endRow` like `infiniteScroll` except with using `treeData` instead. We would normally have the expectation that AG Grid would call the server datasource when it is about to reach a scroll position where it needs to load more data, but it doesn't occur for server-side `treeData`.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of your current implementation? This will help me understand the current setup and the issue .

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out how to get infinite scrolling working with SSRM Tree Data. I felt that the AG Grid documentation was not very clear or emphasized this detail enough.

The key to SSRM Tree Data infinite scrolling is found in the `success` handler you receive as part of the `getRows` request from the AG Grid Server Side Datasource. Two pieces of information you supply to the `success` handler are `rowData` and a `rowCount` number value.

The `rowData` is the information you would get via making whatever server API request you need to fetch data that also consumes the `startRow`/`endRow` info you get from AG Grid and it will only be that subset of data you requested. The crucial piece is the number you supply to `rowCount` -- for infinite scrolling, the expectation is that needs to be set to the **number of rows that are part of the entire group** you just fetched data for and *not* the count of rows you get back from the server fetch.

So if you received a server side datasource request containing the following things:

```
{
    "startRow": 0,
    "endRow": 100,
    "rowGroupCols": [],
    "valueCols": [],
    "pivotCols": [],
    "pivotMode": false,
    "groupKeys": [],
    "filterModel": {},
    "sortModel": []
}
```

(NOTE: The `groupKeys: []` essentially means this request is for the root rows of the tree data grid)

Then you fetch the first 100 rows of the root rows doing your `fetch` API call and then you supply the **total number of rows that are at the root group level** which could be beyond the 100 you just fetched as the initial data like so:

```
const rowData = [...] // first 100 items as per startRow/endRow
const rowCount = ... // this is the total count of rows that exist at the root level in this example
success({ rowData, rowCount });
```